# Gtts python voice

Tags: python, python-3.x

Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть код который преобразует текст в голос.

```
from gtts import gTTS
txt = "текст на русском"
tts = gTTS(text=txt, lang='ru', slow=False)
tts.save("output.mp3")
```

Можно как то изменить голос ?
Сразу скажу, я знаю что можно перевести текст через "pyttsx3", но там произношение не очень, во всяком случае когда читает русский текст и когда попадаются английские слова. По этому вопрос или можно изменить в том коде который написал, или есть ещё какие то варианты ? Спасибо!

Comment: В gtts не нашел выбор голоса, хотя на сайте гугл есть некоторый выбор Russian (Russia) Standard ru-RU ru-RU-Standard-A FEMALE 
Russian (Russia) Standard ru-RU ru-RU-Standard-B MALE 
Russian (Russia) Standard ru-RU ru-RU-Standard-C FEMALE   https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/voices . Вот здесь есть выбор голоса  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-text-speech-python3#0

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подсказать, как можно изменить голос в том коде который я представил?

Comment: Здесь ответ на твой вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37600197/custom-python-gtts-voice

Answer (score 1):

Если кому нужно будет!
Вот код, все работает, нужен только аккаунт cloud google, выбрать cloud text to speech api, активировать и создать пользователя, скачать файл json, и вписать название в код.

```
import os
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]=" -тут имя файлы json, который качается с cloud google console"
from google.cloud import texttospeech

client = texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient()

synthesis_input = texttospeech.SynthesisInput(text="Ричард МакКлинток, профессор латыни из колледжа Hampden-Sydney, штат Вирджиния, взял одно из самых странных слов в Lorem Ipsum, consectetur, и занялся его поисками в классической латинской литературе. ")

voice = texttospeech.VoiceSelectionParams(
language_code='ru-RU',
name='ru-RU-Wavenet-D',
ssml_gender=texttospeech.SsmlVoiceGender.FEMALE)

audio_config = texttospeech.AudioConfig(
audio_encoding=texttospeech.AudioEncoding.MP3)

response = client.synthesize_speech(
input=synthesis_input, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config)

with open('rec.mp3', 'wb') as out:
    out.write(response.audio_content)

    print('Audio conect written to file')
```